# Does killing persist if you revert a save?

Tags: undertale

So, I saw something that said if you kill a certain character:

> Toriel

and reset before saving, you'd still not be blocked off from any endings in the game, including the true pacifist ending, even if Flowey calls you out on it.

I'd really like clarification if this is true or not, and if I have to use the special method to actually delete the memory to see the best ending.

Comment: To hijack the question a bit, does killing any other of the main characters and then loading your save (and then sparing them) screw up the pacifist ending?

Comment: @Pyritie My answer addresses your question as well.

Comment: Generally speaking, while the game will make small saves while you're doing things (Did you talk to the Cactus in the first house? Are you viewing the same scene over four times in a row?) It's only once you've killed someone/thing and continued from that point in which you're prevented from the Pacifrist ending.  Everything else is a note on your adventures.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Your source is correct.** Flowey remembers that you killed that character, but only mentions it once, and it doesn't affect your ability to reach the True Pacifist ending in another playthrough. This is true of any character in the game that you can kill--if you revert your save to a point before you kill them, for the purposes of reaching the True Pacifist ending, it will be as though you never did so.

The only thing which will **permanently** alter the state of your game is

> completing the genocide ending

which can still be reversed by deleting your save file or uninstalling/reinstalling the game.

Comment: Note that you if you have the **Steam version** of the game, you can only reset your game by deleting the save file and playing the game in **offline mode**, as Steam cloud sync automatically saves a backup of your files and will replace it if it is found to be out of sync.

Comment: @ChaseSandmann Not exactly. It can be accomplished via this: http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2470784 (I know because I've done this myself)